# Glassfish 3.1 Clustering

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, load-balancing

First of all, I'm new in glassfish clustering, so excuse me if I ask something stupid.

I'm using glassfish server 3.1, and I've created a new cluster with two local instances (one node). Then I've deployed my web app to the cluster, and now I can access the app from two different ports. Example:

Instance 1   ->   myserver:28080/myapp

Instance 2   ->   myserver:28081/myapp

My question is about how can I config glassfish to let me access the app from one port (for example 8080) what handle for me load-balanced cluster, as:

Cluster (Instance 1 or Instance 2) ->  myserver:8080/myapp

Comment: Please tag more carefully. You tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis], a data mining technique (aka: clustering; but not the clustering that you meant)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either use a hardware load balancer to do that, or to use a web server - like Apache with mod_proxy or mod_jk - to do the load balancing.

Comment: Thanks @John. I've seen your videos about clustering with Glassfish and now I supposed that I could do it with Oracle iPlanet WebServer, is it the way?